# What is this conservatory door part called?

Tags: repair, insulation, doors

There is draft of cold air coming into the house from my conservatory door.

I have noticed that there is a small plastic part that is broken and has left a hole at the bottom of the door.
I don't know what this part is called.

Could someone tell me what it is called so that I can locate a replacement?

[image: hole under the conservatory door]

Another long shot to show where this fits.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those questions without an answer--the part is a proprietary component of the door's [*astragal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astragal), the dividing bar between slabs that provides a latching face and weather seals. You can contact the manufacturer or supplier, or you can attempt a repair.

I'd look at using pop rivets or sheet metal screws along with caulk and some plastic or aluminum sheet to overlay a plate that matches the original size and shape of that part. Add weather stripping if needed to help seal any remaining gap.

Show more photos from different angles for more specific suggestions.